# Extract two Columns from CSV file, split them in while read loop and do different commands with each string

Tags: bash, cut

first I must admit, that I am a noobie with the bash and I am sorry if I did any stupid mistakes. I searched a lot, but I think I am missing the basics.

What I want to do:

- read a csv-file
- get the content of two columns
- create a file with first columns as filename
- and put the content of the second column in that file.

EDIT: This is the sample data:

```
column1;column2;column3-iwant;column4;column5 is what i want;;;
loerm ipsum; dolor sit ame;filename;consetur;the content i want in the file;;;
justo;labore;myfilename2;labore;;sometimes something here;
```

My first attempt was very promising:

```
cut -d\; -f3,5 myFile.csv | while read line; do echo $line; done
```

I get the following output:

```
filename1; Value1, Value2, Value3
filename2, Value B, ValueC, ValueD
```

What I now want to do is split this string with ";" as delimiter and create a file "filename1.txt" and put the content "Value1, Value2, Value3" in this file.

I tried the next step as follows

```
cut -d\; -f3,5 myFile.csv | while read line; do filname=$(echo "$line" | cut -d\; -f1) | echo $filename; done
```

This prints $line for every loop

Next bet:

```
cut -d\; -f3,5 myfile.csv | while read line; do filename=`echo $line | cut -d\; -f1` | mycontent=`echo $line | cut -d\; -f2` | echo "$filename"; done
```

Quite close but it prints for every loop the last row of the csv-file.

What is my mistake?
Cheers
David

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Hi Cyrus, Kylie could help me but here is the same data (edit in the post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David!

I am a newbie here as well, but I think I have the answer.

If you create a script file with this content and make it executable, you can then type ./script.bash NameOfMyFile.csv and it will do your trick.  You can at least use this code as a place to start. Good luck!

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
while IFS=';' read -r newfile contents 
do
   echo "Create file: $newfile  ==> with contents: $contents"
   echo $contents > $newfile
done < "$file"
```

The sample file I fed it looked like this:

```
Name1; Put this stuff in the first place I want it And then put in more stuff
Name2; I might, have some; puncuated stuff! But it shouldn't matter.
Name3; 20394)@(#$
Name4; No newline at the end of this line
```

Output:

```
Create file: Name1  ==> with contents:  Put this stuff in the first place I want it And then put in more stuff
Create file: Name2  ==> with contents:  I might, have some; puncuated stuff! But it shouldn't matter.
Create file: Name3  ==> with contents:  20394)@(#$
Create file: Name4  ==> with contents:  No newline at the end of this line
```

I hope this helps!
Kylie

Comment: Thanks Kylie - it took a while and I don't understand all of how it works but it works :-) My problem was that the csv file had more than the two columns und I only want column 3 and 5 but I put all in the while-read-loop and only put the ones out, that I want.